# How to auto remove document after certain days from mongodb collection with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

As title, How to auto remove document after certain days from mongodb collection with meteor?

Mongodb have [expire data](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) feature but how to make it work with meteor? Does it possible currently?

thank You...

Comment: hi @chridam i don't know that question exist. thank you for reference,,

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on the server using `Meteor.setTimeout()`.

You can also use cron tasks to do this and there packages that will help you with cron tasks such as: `percolate:synced-cron` (https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron)

In a case where the date is far away, you won't be able to use `Meteor.setTimeout()`. What you should do in cases such as these is run a cron task that runs perhaps every 24 hours. In this cron task you check which docs need to be deleted in the next 24 hours and set a timeout to delete the appropriate docs in that 24 hour period.

Answer (score 0):

You can expire data in MongoDB by creating TTL index. If you run the following script in the MongoDB shell, `log_events` entries will be automatically removed after an hour:

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

This feature uses a  background thread in mongod that reads the date-typed values in the index and removes expired documents from the collection, so it works independently of Meteor. Just for completeness, in order for this to work you need to set createdAt to the current time, when adding a new document:

```
 db.log_events.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(),
   "logEvent": 2,
  "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

Comment: To further expand completeness: documents are not removed in the second they expire. It may take up to a minute for the documents to be removed.